# cxcore210d.dll not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

i've the following code that processes an image. it uses opencv. i've installed and configured opencv as described but my application can't find cxcore210d.dll. my linker->input->additional dependencies is set to include

```
cxcore210d.lib;highgui210d.lib;cv210.lib;cxcore210.lib;highgui210.lib;cxcore210d.lib;
```

.
Any ideas why this file can't be found?

.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"    
    #include <cv.h>
    #include <highgui.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <iostream>


    void sampleImage(const IplImage* arr, float idx0, float idx1, CvScalar& res)
    {
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(cvGetSize(arr).height-1) || idx1>(cvGetSize(arr).width-1)){
        res.val[0]=0;
        res.val[1]=0;
        res.val[2]=0;
        res.val[3]=0;
        return;
      }
      float idx0_fl=floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=ceil(idx1);

      CvScalar s1=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      CvScalar s2=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      CvScalar s3=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      CvScalar s4=cvGet2D(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);
      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;
      res.val[0]= s1.val[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[0]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[0]*x*y + s4.val[0]*x*(1-y);
      res.val[1]= s1.val[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[1]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[1]*x*y + s4.val[1]*x*(1-y);
      res.val[2]= s1.val[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[2]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[2]*x*y + s4.val[2]*x*(1-y);
      res.val[3]= s1.val[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2.val[3]*(1-x)*y + s3.val[3]*x*y + s4.val[3]*x*(1-y);
    }

    float xscale;
    float yscale;
    float xshift;
    float yshift;

    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){
      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float thresh = 1;
    float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){
      float x3 = x1+(x2-x1)*0.5;
      float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
      float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

      //  std::cerr<<"x1: "<<x1<<" - "<<res1<<" x3: "<<x3<<" - "<<res3<<std::endl;

      if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
        return x1;
      if(res3<0){
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
      }
      else{
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
      }
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Mat/Pictures/gsxr1.jpg",1);//cvLoadImage( argv[1], 1 );
      IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth,src->nChannels);
      IplImage* dst2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src),src->depth,src->nChannels);
      float K=atof(argv[3]);
      float centerX=atoi(argv[4]);
      float centerY=atoi(argv[5]);
      int width = cvGetSize(src).width;
      int height = cvGetSize(src).height;

      xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,K);
      float newcenterX = width-centerX;
      float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,K);

      yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,K);
      float newcenterY = height-centerY;
      float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,K);
      //  scale = (centerX-xshift)/centerX;
      xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
      yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;

      std::cerr<<xshift<<" "<<yshift<<" "<<xscale<<" "<<yscale<<std::endl;
      std::cerr<<cvGetSize(src).height<<std::endl;
      std::cerr<<cvGetSize(src).width<<std::endl;

      for(int j=0;j<cvGetSize(dst).height;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<cvGetSize(dst).width;i++){
          CvScalar s;
          float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,K);
          float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,K);
          sampleImage(src,y,x,s);
          cvSet2D(dst,j,i,s);

        }
      }
    #if 0
      cvNamedWindow( "Source1", 1 );
      cvShowImage( "Source1", dst);
      cvWaitKey(0);
    #endif

      cvSaveImage(argv[2],dst,0);

    #if 0
      for(int j=0;j<cvGetSize(src).height;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<cvGetSize(src).width;i++){
          CvScalar s;
          sampleImage(src,j+0.25,i+0.25,s);
          cvSet2D(dst,j,i,s);
        }
      }

      cvNamedWindow( "Source1", 1 );
      cvShowImage( "Source1", src);
      cvWaitKey(0);

    #endif  

}
```

Comment: Do you have the DLL? Is it in the same directory as the executable? If not, is it at least in a directory of the system path (PATH environment variable)?

Comment: @bart hi, sorry but i'm new to c++ and vis studio, i'm coming from android, could you explain the steps involved to check what you're asking? i'm not sure if i've done anything with the system path

Comment: Well, it has nothing to do with code, visual studio, c++ or anything like that. ;) First things first, can you confirm you actually have the DLL it is missing? If so, where is it located in relation to the executable you're trying to run?

Comment: @bart :) going to sound stupid here, how do i check if i have the DLL?

Comment: You have all the opencv libs. So I assume the DLLs would be in a similar directory? Or at least somewhere close? If not, just search your entire HD for the file. :)

Comment: @bart ok found it. it's in the opencv2.1/bin directory

Comment: Then either [add the path](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) to your PATH environment variable (link is for XP, but other versions are similar), or copy the DLLs into the same directory as your executable.

Comment: @bart hey thanks the app still doesn't work but the dlls are all found now. it's the same as adding .jars to your path, i didn't realize. create an answer and i'll accept if you like:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to "cxcore210d.dll not found" this actually has nothing to do with your code. Your application simply can't find the DLL.

To solve this you can do the following:

- Take a copy of your DLL and place it in the same directory as you executable
- Add the directory where your DLL can be found to the system path. That is, the PATH environment variable in Windows. (An example for XP can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519), but the principle is the same for other versions)

This should solve the error you're reporting. However, as karlphillip suggests, you do also seem to be linking against both the release and debug versions of the libraries. So besides the steps above, do take note of his suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries ending with **d**, such as *cxcore210d.lib* and *highgui210d.lib*, are used for debug builds. So you most probably want to use the release builds: `cv210.lib cxcore210.lib highgui210.lib`

Notice that you have declared some of the libraries more then once.

I suggest you follow this [tutorial at willowgarage](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC++_VS2010) to properly configure VS2010.

Comment: That tutorial is the problem. Because if you follow the instructions everything works fine except for that library thing!

Answer (score 1):

1.Check your environment variables: Computer->Properties->Advanced system settings->Environment variables. For user variables, add new variable of this path: PATH\OpenCV-2.1.0\bin. (Path is where you install the OpenCV program);

2.Go to your project, set your Debug and Release properties in Property Manager. Set the Executable Directories as following: PATH\OpenCV-2.1.0\bin\Debug for Debug and PATH\OpenCV-2.1.0\bin\Release for Release;

3.After these if there is an error window pops up and says sth like '...dll is missing', then copy whatever missing .dll into your project's Debug file.

I tried 1 and 2, but no one told me about 3. And now it works perfectly. Hope this will help